# Bash script that accepts TCP connection, when a client connection occurs, send the time of day as a response to the client

Tags: bash

I'm not going to lie this is an homework assignment, but I've been googling constantly to try to get some idea on how the heck to approach this particular question.

"Create a script named lab6s6 that accepts TCP connections. When a client connection
occurs, send the time of day as a response to client. You may choose any port number as
the listening port, and don’t forget to close your connections."

I'm running the latest fedora OS on my virtualbox

So far after doing some research I've come across this particular piece of code

> `$ exec {file-descriptor}<>/dev/{protocol}/{host}/{port}`

What i've come up with after doing some research would be

```
exec 3<>/dev/TCP/127.0.0.1/8000
```

So from my general understanding the file descriptor tends to always be set to 3 (is this because of the stdin, stdout, stderr, what is the purpose of this?) also the "<>" which represents reading and writing, and the directory is a way to actually use those protocols. and lastly, for my ip I read somewhere that I shouldnt be using the loopback that this wouldn't work but I'll be honest I was a bit clueless while reading the article, and for the port I never really understood that, is it like the higher the number the more available your signal is?

and another side question, do I need to install any other type of software to even accomplish something like this? If anyone could clarify if I'm basically opening up like a phone line on my computer to be able to talk to other computers at are on my LAN, is that even possible?

I'm not asking for direct answers, but if someone could nudge me in the right direction I would appreciate it greatly!

Thanks again!

Comment: Are you allowed to use any tools? Netcat (`nc`) is available for most systems that I've used, and can listen for a connection. If you use the `-v` flag, Netcat will give you the incoming connection's IP address.

Comment: Our professor didn't give us any restrictions on tools from what I know, on regards to netcat, this tool would essentially allow me to open up like a means of communicating between different virtual machines that i make? Could anyone give me an idea of what is actually suppose to happen, my understanding is to allow one of my virtual machines to speak to the other, does that sound about right? or do you feel like there is a better way to picture this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have prepared for you two scripts: client and server
after giving them the execution right: *chmod u+x script_name* you can run them in any order (client -> server or server -> client)

bash_server.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#define port on which the server will listen
#and the output file that will be used to store the client port to send an answer
readonly PORT_LISTEN=22222;
readonly SERVER_FILE=server_file_tmp.out;

echo "Removing the server temporary file: ${SERVER_FILE}";
rm -f "${SERVER_FILE}";
#will open/bind/listen on PORT_LISTEN and whenever some information is received 
#it will write it in the SERVER FILE
echo "Starting the server on port: ${PORT_LISTEN} with configuration file: ${SERVER_FILE}";
nc -k -l "${PORT_LISTEN}" | tee "${SERVER_FILE}" &

echo "Waiting for connection..."
#active listening to entry connection
while true; 
do
    #get always information about the external connection trying to connect to our open port
    tmpNetworkString=$(lsof -i:"${PORT_LISTEN}" | grep "localhost:${PORT_LISTEN} (ESTABLISHED)" | awk '{print $9}');
    echo -n "${tmpNetworkString}";
    if [ -s "${SERVER_FILE}" ] && [ ! -z "${tmpNetworkString}" ]; then
        answerPORT=$(cat "${SERVER_FILE}");
        echo "Connection received on port ${PORT_LISTEN}...";
        incomingIP=$(echo $tmpNetworkString | cut -d':' -f1);
        incomingPort=$(echo $tmpNetworkString | cut -d'-' -f1 | cut -d':' -f2);
        echo ">>Incoming traffic IP: ${incomingIP}";
        echo ">>Incoming traffic Port: ${incomingPort}";
        echo "Answering on IP: ${incomingIP}, port: ${answerPORT}...";
        #wait client port to be ready
        nc -z "${incomingIP}" "${answerPORT}";
        isOpen=$?;
        while [ ! "${isOpen}" -eq 0 ];
        do
            nc -z "${incomingIP}" "${answerPORT}";
            isOpen=$?;
        done
        echo $(date) | nc -q 2 "${incomingIP}" "${answerPORT}";
        echo "Closing the server, port: ${PORT_LISTEN}";
        fuser -k -n tcp "${PORT_LISTEN}";
        echo "Removing the server temporary file: ${SERVER_FILE}";
        rm -f "${SERVER_FILE}";
        exit 0;
    fi
done
```

bash_client.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#define port on which the client will listen
#and the output file that will be used to store the answer from the server
readonly PORT_LISTEN=33333;
readonly CLIENT_FILE=client_file_tmp.out;
readonly SERVER_PORT=22222;
readonly SERVER_IP=localhost

echo "Removing the client temporary file: ${CLIENT_FILE}";
rm -f "${CLIENT_FILE}";
#will open/bind/listen on PORT_LISTEN and whenever some information is received 
#it will write it in the CLIENT FILE
echo "Starting the server on port: ${PORT_LISTEN} with configuration file: ${CLIENT_FILE}";
nc -k -l "${PORT_LISTEN}" > "${CLIENT_FILE}" &

echo "Connecting to the server: ${SERVER_IP}, on port: ${SERVER_PORT} and waiting for answer";
#sending port information for answer:

#wait client port to be ready
nc -z "${SERVER_IP}" "${SERVER_PORT}";
isOpen=$?;
while [ ! "${isOpen}" -eq 0 ];
do
    nc -z "${SERVER_IP}" "${SERVER_PORT}";
    isOpen=$?;
done
echo "${PORT_LISTEN}" | nc -q 2 "${SERVER_IP}" "${SERVER_PORT}";

while true; 
do
    if [ -s "${CLIENT_FILE}" ]; then
        echo "Answer received from server...";
        echo "##############################";
        echo "##############################";
        cat "${CLIENT_FILE}";
        echo "##############################";
        echo "##############################";
        #sleep 10;
        echo "Closing the open port of the client, port: ${PORT_LISTEN}";
        fuser -k -n tcp "${PORT_LISTEN}";
        echo "Removing the answer file: ${CLIENT_FILE}";
        rm -f "${CLIENT_FILE}";
        exit 0;
    fi
done
```

Comment: thank you for the above information, but it seems that I'm still not able to get my two virtual machines to communicate among each other, I've been playing with my firewall and did

Comment: First of all you should try to run both scripts on the same machine (using localhost) and if it works as you want then try to run it from 2 different machines, they should be able to communicate (be in the same network, and there should not be NAT/firewall between them, when this is working you can play with the network configuration)